# Call a Stored Procedure within an Output clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a calendar table that I want to take a todays scheduled items and duplicate the records, keeping most of the data and make a few changes to some of the fields, that works fine.

The problem is with calling the stored procedure. I need to create another record in a different table and return the scope identity ID.

The sp inserts takes the inserted data from the Update and uses it to create the new record then returns a scope identity.

I tried using a function but it doesn't like to do inserts. How can I call this sp within this statement?

```
UPDATE calendar_tbl
SET WO=0
OUTPUT 
    inserted.startDate, 
    dateadd(ss, 0, inserted.startDate), 
    inserted.text, 
    inserted.color, 
    inserted.tColor,
    dbo.funcEpoch(inserted.startDate),
    '',
    inserted.id,
    exec dbo.sp_create @AccountNumber,inserted.CompanyID ,inserted.LocationID, inserted.text,inserted.startDate, dateadd(ss, 0, inserted.startDate), inserted.UserID,'',
    inserted.UserID,
    inserted.LocationID,
    inserted.CompanyID,
    inserted.AccountNumber,
    0
    INTO 
        calendar_tbl(
            startDate, 
            endDate,
            text,
            color,
            tColor,
            evLength,
            rtype,
            PID,
            WOID,
            UserID,
            LocationID,
            CompanyID,
            AccountNumber,
            WOorSchedule)
WHERE   
    (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, startDate, 101)) = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 101)) AND
    accountNumber = @AccountNumber
```

Comment: You cannot call functions or procedures inside the `OUTPUT` clause. The clause is **only** intended to store row data that's been inserted, updated or deleted into a temporary or permanent table - it does **not** support any data manipulation while doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use composable DML to nest an UPDATE, INSERT and capture the auditIds.  Simple example below:

```
USE tempdb
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Create a table
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sampleTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.sampleTable
CREATE TABLE dbo.sampleTable ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, someData UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID(), dateAdded DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(), addedBy VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT SUSER_NAME(), dateModified DATETIME, ts ROWVERSION )
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.auditTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.auditTable
CREATE TABLE dbo.auditTable ( auditId INT IDENTITY(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY, rowId INT, someData UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, dateAdded DATETIME, addedBy VARCHAR(30), ts ROWVERSION )
GO

-- Populate table
INSERT INTO dbo.sampleTable DEFAULT VALUES
GO 100


-- Example composable DML query to do both UPDATE, INSERT and record new auditIds
INSERT INTO dbo.auditTable ( rowId, someData, dateAdded, addedBy )
OUTPUT inserted.auditId
SELECT rowId, someData, dateAdded, addedBy
FROM
    (
    UPDATE TOP(10) t1
    SET dateModified = GETDATE()
    OUTPUT inserted.rowId, inserted.someData, inserted.dateAdded, inserted.addedBy
    FROM dbo.sampleTable t1
    WHERE dateModified IS NULL
    ) x


SELECT *
FROM dbo.sampleTable
WHERE dateModified IS NOT NULL

SELECT *
FROM dbo.auditTable
```

Would something like that work for you?